# max and group by question with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, max

I want to group the below query by `GetSetDomainName` and select the row which has the maximum `GetSetKalanGun`.In other words, I am trying to get the row with the maximum KALANGUN among those which have the same DOMAINNAME.

```
var kayitlar3 = (
    from rows in islemDetayKayitListesi
    select new
    {
        KAYITNO = rows.GetSetKayitNo,
        HESAPADI = rows.GetSetHesapAdi,
        URUNNO = rows.GetSetUrunNo,
        URUNADI = rows.GetSetUrunAdi,
        URUNMIKTAR = rows.GetSetUrunMiktar,

        ISLEMTARIHI = rows.GetSetIslemTarihi,
        HIZMETDURUMU = rows.GetSetHizmetDurumu,
        TOPLAMTUTAR = rows.GetSetToplamTutar,

        HIZMETBASLANGICTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi,
        HIZMETBITISTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi,
        KALANGUN = rows.GetSetKalanGun 
        DOMAINNAME = rows.GetSetDomainName,
        SIPARISDURUMU = rows.GetSetSiparisDurumu
    }).AsQueryable();
```

This is what I get

```
KAYITNO DOMAINNAME KALANGUN
1       asdf.com      30
2       domnam.com    172
3       asdf.com      40
4       xyz.com       350
```

This is what I want

```
KAYITNO DOMAINNAME KALANGUN
 2       domnam.com    172
 3       asdf.com      40
 4       xyz.com       350

var islemDetayKayitListesi = new List<IslemDetayKayit>();
```

`islemDetayKayitListesi` get filled with a foreach loop, with no problem

And that is what `IslemDetayKayit` looks like

```
public class IslemDetayKayit
{
    public int GetSetKayitNo { get; set; }
    public string GetSetHesapAdi { get; set; }
    public string GetSetUrunNo { get; set; }
    public string GetSetUrunAdi { get; set; }
    public double GetSetUrunMiktar { get; set; }
    public string GetSetIslemTarihi { get; set; }
    public string GetSetHizmetDurumu { get; set; }
    public string GetSetToplamTutar { get; set; }
    public string GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }
    public string GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi { get; set; }
    public int GetSetKalanGun { get; set; }
    public string GetSetSiparisDurumu { get; set; }
    public string GetSetDomainName { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** : I figured out that there was some other problem in my code, and corrected it.After that all the answer I had to this question works.Thank you for helping and teaching me new things.

Comment: Wouldn't the result row be the same whether you grouped or not?  The maximum won't change.

Comment: I really am not sure @Inuyasha.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: you're going to have to elaborate further as your sample output doesn't quite make sense. Do you want to skip ALL rows until you reach the maximal row and then output the rest?

Comment: Yes @sixlettervariables that is what I want to do.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: Why are you calling `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: @Steven I needed that before some changes Mr.Steven it didn't do any harm yet, and I tried everything after I removed and nothing changed, too.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: Converting an in-memory enumerable to an queryable is hardly ever a solution. It will only slow down the execution enormously. The only useful scenario I've seen is for unit testing to mimic a LINQ provider. So if it isn't there for a special reason, loose the `AsQueryable`.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: You might need to work on your language skills.  Take a look at how I refactored your code. Please loose the `GetSet` prefix on the properties. It doesn't add anything. As a matter of fact; it just makes it harder to read the code.

Comment: thank you Mr.Steven, I will. @Steven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
var kayitlar3 = 
    islemDetayKayitListesi.
    Select(rows => 
    new
    {
        KAYITNO = rows.GetSetKayitNo,
        HESAPADI = rows.GetSetHesapAdi,
        URUNNO = rows.GetSetUrunNo,
        URUNADI = rows.GetSetUrunAdi,
        URUNMIKTAR = rows.GetSetUrunMiktar,

        ISLEMTARIHI = rows.GetSetIslemTarihi,
        HIZMETDURUMU = rows.GetSetHizmetDurumu,
        TOPLAMTUTAR = rows.GetSetToplamTutar,

        HIZMETBASLANGICTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi,
        HIZMETBITISTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi,
        KALANGUN = rows.GetSetKalanGun,
        DOMAINNAME = rows.GetSetDomainName,
        SIPARISDURUMU = rows.GetSetSiparisDurumu
    }).
    GroupBy(a => 
        //To ignore case and trailing/leading whitespace
        a.DOMAINNAME.ToUpper().Trim()).
    Select(g => 
         g.OrderByDescending(a => a.KALANGUN).FirstOrDefault()).
    AsQueryable();
```

EDIT:

So using this code:

```
        List<Thing> islemDetayKayitListesi = new List<Thing>();
        Thing a = new Thing() { GetSetDomainName = "abc.com", GetSetKayitNo = 1,
            GetSetKalanGun = 40 };
        Thing b = new Thing() { GetSetDomainName = "abc.com", GetSetKayitNo = 2, 
            GetSetKalanGun = 300 };
        Thing c = new Thing() { GetSetDomainName = "xyz.com", GetSetKayitNo = 3, 
            GetSetKalanGun = 400 };
        Thing d = new Thing() { GetSetDomainName = "123.com", GetSetKayitNo = 4, 
            GetSetKalanGun = 124 };
        islemDetayKayitListesi.Add(a);
        islemDetayKayitListesi.Add(b);
        islemDetayKayitListesi.Add(c);
        islemDetayKayitListesi.Add(d);
        var kayitlar3 =
            islemDetayKayitListesi.
                Select(rows =>
                new
                {
                    KAYITNO = rows.GetSetKayitNo,
                    HESAPADI = rows.GetSetHesapAdi,
                    URUNNO = rows.GetSetUrunNo,
                    URUNADI = rows.GetSetUrunAdi,
                    URUNMIKTAR = rows.GetSetUrunMiktar,

                    ISLEMTARIHI = rows.GetSetIslemTarihi,
                    HIZMETDURUMU = rows.GetSetHizmetDurumu,
                    TOPLAMTUTAR = rows.GetSetToplamTutar,

                    HIZMETBASLANGICTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi,
                    HIZMETBITISTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi,
                    KALANGUN = rows.GetSetKalanGun,
                    DOMAINNAME = rows.GetSetDomainName,
                    SIPARISDURUMU = rows.GetSetSiparisDurumu
                }).
                GroupBy(anon =>
                    anon.DOMAINNAME).
                Select(g =>
                    g.OrderByDescending(anon => anon.KALANGUN).First()).
                AsQueryable();
        kayitlar3.ToList().
            ForEach(anon => Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
                anon.KAYITNO, anon.DOMAINNAME, anon.KALANGUN));

    struct Thing 
    {
        public int GetSetKayitNo { get; set; }
        public int GetSetHesapAdi { get; set; }
        public int GetSetUrunNo { get; set; }
        public int GetSetUrunAdi { get; set; }
        public int GetSetUrunMiktar { get; set; }

        public int GetSetIslemTarihi { get; set; }
        public int GetSetHizmetDurumu { get; set; }
        public int GetSetToplamTutar { get; set; }

        public int GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }
        public int GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi { get; set; }
        public int GetSetKalanGun { get; set; }
        public string GetSetDomainName { get; set; }
        public int GetSetSiparisDurumu { get; set; }
    }
```

I get the expected output:

```
2, abc.com, 300
3, xyz.com, 400
4, 123.com, 124
```

Comment: this is giving me to many error `islemDetayKayitListesi` is a list of `IslemDetayKayit`.thah might be the cause, and thanks.

Comment: thanks for your interest Streudel, I hope you check the question update.This is giving the same result with Mr.Steven's answer.

Comment: So it is printing two sections for asdf.com? Those strings would have to be different in order for that to occur. Is there perhaps trailing spaces or a case mismatch that would cause them to not compare as equal?

Comment: No I am only getting this output `KAYITNO DOMAINNAME KALANGUN 4 xyz.com 350 ` one row that has the max KALANGUN among all rows.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it out, it totally works and returns all rows.

Comment: Interesting, I am still getting one row.Thank you so much, I will give it another shot.

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick:

```
var q =
    from item in kayitlar3
    group item by item.DOMAINNAME into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(i => i.KALANGUN).First();
```

You can also try this:

```
var q = 
    from row in islemDetayKayitListesi
    group row by row.GetSetDomainName into g
    let highest = g.OrderByDescending(r => r.GetSetKalanGun).First()
    select new
    {
        KAYITNO = highest.GetSetKayitNo,
        DOMAINNAME = g.Key,
        KALANGUN = highest.GetSetKalanGun
    };
```

Note that this would yield the same results. If it doesn't, there is a problem with your code that we can't see by looking at the information that you posted.

Comment: yes, good thinking Mr.Steven.However, not the result I wanted I guess I am not making my point clear.I will just show some output and my desired output.thank you very much.

Comment: I added some details about the expected output @Mr.Steven, could you give me any ideas with that?

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: After reading your update, my answer still stands. It does give the desired output. The `q` variable contains a list of anonymous types where each `DOMAINNAME` is unique and contains the item with the highest `KALANGUN` among items with the same `DOMAINNAME`. This is exactly what you are asking and what you are showing in your update.

Comment: However the output I get is `KAYITNO DOMAINNAME KALANGUN                      4       xyz.com       350`

Comment: thanks for your replys, I will try these and check other parts of my code.

Answer (score 1):

**After clarification about your desired output**, this will return the row with the top KALANGUN per DOMAINNAME:

```
var kayitlar3 = (
from rows in islemDetayKayitListesi
select new
{
    KAYITNO = rows.GetSetKayitNo,
    HESAPADI = rows.GetSetHesapAdi,
    URUNNO = rows.GetSetUrunNo,
    URUNADI = rows.GetSetUrunAdi,
    URUNMIKTAR = rows.GetSetUrunMiktar,

    ISLEMTARIHI = rows.GetSetIslemTarihi,
    HIZMETDURUMU = rows.GetSetHizmetDurumu,
    TOPLAMTUTAR = rows.GetSetToplamTutar,

    HIZMETBASLANGICTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBaslangicTarihi,
    HIZMETBITISTARIHI = rows.GetSetHizmetBitisTarihi,
    KALANGUN = rows.GetSetKalanGun 
    DOMAINNAME = rows.GetSetDomainName,
    SIPARISDURUMU = rows.GetSetSiparisDurumu
})
.GroupBy(rr => rr.DOMAINNAME)
.SelectMany(gg => gg.OrderByDescending(rr => rr.KALANGUN).First());
```

Comment: Hım, thanks for the try,I guess I misdirected you in my comment Mr.sixlettervariables.I updated my desired output what I want to do is choosing the row with the maximum KALANGUN among those which have the same DOMAINNAME.That is why I thought I may need a group by. @sixlettervariables

Comment: Ok, so you want the maximum KALANGUN per DOMAINNAME.

Comment: :D yes, thanks the row with the max KALANGUN per DOMAINNAME, I dont want to cause no more misunderstandings.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: Edited to reflect your request.

Comment: I have 11 errors with this version Mr.sixlettervariables one of them is `'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Order' and no extension method 'Order' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I removed `AsQueryable`, not sure why it is needed.

Comment: Interesting, what type is `islemDetayKayitListesi`?

Comment: it is a List `List<IslemDetayKayit> islemDetayKayitListesi = new List<IslemDetayKayit>();`. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  from rows in islemDetayKayitListesi 
  group rows by new { rows.GetSetDomainName} into results
  let MaxKALANGUN = results.Max(i=>i.KALANGUN)
  select new 
  { 
        KAYITNO = results.First(i=>i.KALANGUN== MaxKALANGUN).GetSetKayitNo
        DOMAINNAME = results.Key.GetSetDomainName , 
        KALANGUN = MaxKALANGUN
  }
```

If you want the complete class, try

```
  from rows in islemDetayKayitListesi 
  group rows by new { rows.GetSetDomainName} into results
  let MaxKALANGUN = results.Max(i=>i.KALANGUN)
  select results.First(i=>i.KALANGUN== MaxKALANGUN)
```

Comment: this will cause me to lose so many data even if this part works, I guess I can solve it with adding all values of islemDetayKayitListesi,well I need time thanks I will try it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it as soon as it is possible and feedback.

Comment: Well it is again only one row just like the other answers with max KALANGUN.Thank you for trying.

Comment: Given the input you mention, this definitely returns three items, as does other solutions mentioned, so there must be some else wrong with your code.  I would try creating a test solution maybe even using the code from FlyingStreudel to see if that works and then compare that with your code.

Comment: I edited my question sgmoore it works, actually all the answers work, thank you so much.